# Ember.js and API pagination

Tags: ember.js, model, pagination, promise

I'm using Ember.js (v1.2.0) with an API which returns paginated JSON data like this:

```
{
    "count": 5, 
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/some/resource/?page=2", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 37, 
            "title": "Some title", 
            "description": "Some description", 
        }, 
        {
            "id": 35, 
            "title": "Sdflskdf", 
            "description": "sdfkdsjf", 
        }, 
        {
            "id": 34, 
            "title": "Some other title", 
            "description": "Dsdlfksdf", 
        }, 
    ]
}
```

I'm **not** using ember-data, so I'm using a plain ember object as my model and loading the data like this:

```
App.SomeResource = Ember.Object.extend({});

App.SomeResource.reopenClass({
    find: function () {
        return $.getJSON('/some/resource/').then(function (response) {
            return response.results.map(function (data) {
                return App.SomeResource.create(data);
            });
        });
    },
});
```

The find method on my model class returns a promise which resolves to an array of objects. While creates SomeResource objects, all the pagination data is lost.

Is there a way to store `count`, `next` and `previous` page urls somewhere when the promise resolves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than storing this metadata on the global `window` object, I came up with this:

```
App.SomeResource.reopenClass({
    find: function () {
        var url = '/some/resource/';
        return Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function (response) {
            response.results = response.results.map(function (resource) {
                return App.SomeResource.create(resource);
            });
            return response;
        });
    },
});
```

`SomeResource.find()` just instantiates Ember objects from the results array and then returns the response with the rest of the data untouched. The route then receives the response and sets up the pagination data **and** the model in the `setupController` function:

```
App.SomeResourceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.SomeResource.find();
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.setProperties({count: model.count,
                                  pageCount: model.page_count,
                                  currentPage: model.current_page,
                                  pageRange: model.page_range,
                                  previous: model.previous,
                                  next: model.next,
                                  model: model.results,});
    },
});
```

It works, but maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I am assigning them to global object but you should do better.

```
App.SomeResource = Ember.Object.extend({});

App.SomeResource.reopenClass({
    find: function () {
        return $.getJSON('/some/resource/').then(function (response) {
            return RSVP.all(response.results.map(function (data) {
                return App.SomeResource.create(data);
            })).then(function(createdResources) {
                window.count = response.count;
                window.next = response.next;
                window.previous = response.previous;
                return createdResources;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems to work, but if I'm paginating several models it would overwrite the metadata.